# What objects and APIs would I use to fill the unity game window with custom graphics?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to build an app using Unity which doesn't use a traditional camera to generate the graphics.  I'll build them using some custom shaders and a few cameras whose results get stuffed in rendertextures and then frobbed.  (Think http://www.purplefrog.com/~thoth/art/kaleidescope/kaleid1.html but even weirder)

I'm not sure what objects I would put in the scene to accomplish this.  In any normal app you just put a camera and point it at the right spot and Unity gets the pixels into the window, but that is just not how this thing will work.

I'm not sure if I should be using a UI Canvas or what APIs would be used to copy various render textures into the proper locations.

Comment: Theres some youtube videos on making mirrors, perhaps all you need are a bunch of mirrors?

Comment: You can use screen space `Image` or `Sprite` as the render surface. Write a shader that takes in render textures and blend them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **not** targeting WebGL you can create a RenderTexture of the proper size (maybe using `RenderTexture.GetTemporary`) and use `Graphics.CopyTexture` or other techniques to assemble the image you want displayed in the game window.

Once you have the pixels you want in the RenderTexture you can use `Graphics.Blit(src, (RenderTexture)null);` which will copy the pixels into the game window.  These pixels will be stretched if the game window is not the same size as the RenderTexture.

This technique worked for me in the editor's game window, but when I compile it to WebGL, all I get is a mostly-grey screen with a really big black rectangle in the bottom left.